# Where can I ask for help identifying products?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to know where I should ask for help identifying products. e.g.

- "What glasses is X wearing in the movie Y?"
- "Does anyone know which table was featured in X?"
- "Who makes this poster?"

Should I choose the closest sub-site to that product? 
Is there a specific tag I should use? 
etc.

Answer (score 1):

> "What glasses is X wearing in the movie Y?"

If you are trying to identify a prop used in a movie/show, it **could** be on topic for Movies.SE. Make sure you read their meta or ask if you can't find anything.

> - "Does anyone know which table was featured in X?"

- "Who makes this poster?"

The other two, are for most [not fitting for the Stack Exchange Q&A style](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) by the kind of quality they tend to attract. If you have a question about something like this, make sure you actually can't find any information (and by that I mean reaching the [second page of Google results](http://xkcd.com/1334/)), and even so isn't sure that your question will be well retrieved.

Comment: Prop identification is off-topic until it have significance in story understanding.